# Google's Terms of Service

Tags: copyright, terms-of-service, google

How to interpret Google's Terms of Service with respect to this statement: "*You may not copy, modify, distribute, sell, or lease any part of our services or software*" that can be found under the *Software in Google services* section. Does that mean I can't copy a URL in Google Chrome, translation generated by Google translate or any other content that I find on a Google service?

Answer (score 2):

No. I understand that to mean you may not attempt to province the same service that Google does, in full or in part, by copying Google software. It does not refer to the output of the service, such as a translation or a map. It does refer to the ability to, on demand, convert a query or other input into that output.

URLs will be either input or output.  The service is to be able to take an imput phrase, say "Washington monument" and return a set of URLs of pages about the monument. The service is the ability to take 'white house" and return a map showing where the White House is,and what is near it. And so on.